# How can I include the WindowTitle column in the output from tasklist?

Tags: cmd, tasklist

I'm getting the below output from the command `tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe"`

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
cmd.exe                      16156 Console                    1      2,636 K
cmd.exe                      12484 Console                    1      2,396 K
cmd.exe                      49628 Console                    1      2,852 K
cmd.exe                      42664 Console                    1      2,824 K
cmd.exe                      49956 Console                    1      3,288 K
```

I saw an option to search by WindowTitle, but is there any option to get that WindowTitle column in the output?

Comment: Well, have you never tried `tasklist`'s verbosity switch `/V`?

Comment: @aschipfl, yes i also found this option now, didnt know it provides the title, tnx anyway !!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found an answer using /V, it provides also the window title.

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v
```

Comment: If you still want it as a table don't ask for it to be formatted as a list, _(`/fo list`)_. Either just omit that option, `%systemroot%\system32\tasklist.exe /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v`, because `table` is the default, or stipulate it, `%systemroot%\system32\tasklist.exe /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /fo table /v`.

Comment: Finally the list presentation is more comfortable for me, but thanks a lot !

Comment: That may well be Adir D, but please note that you asked the question which stated, "How can I include the WindowTitle column in the output from tasklist?" and only the table format presents the output in columns. Your answer does not present the output in columns and therefore does not fulfil the question. For the purpose of presenting a solution to the asked question, you need to remove the list format from your answer. In your own script outside of this site you can have whichever format you prefer, but that does not alter the question you asked, or any solutions presented.

Comment: @Compo, yes, you can write an answer if you want instead of the comment above

Comment: Just remove `/fo list` from yours!